# List of list sorting in Python elegant solution

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have the following code to sort a list of lists by the last element:

```
a = [['a','num1','num2','num3'],['b','ind1','ind2','ind3'],['c',12,0,24],['d',0,0,0],['e',3,5,100]]

print(a)
b,c = a[:2],a[2:]
d= c.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
e = b+d

print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
print(e)
```

I would think that e would have the sorted list. But it does not work.
d is none

I tried the following code too

```
a = [['a','num1','num2','num3'],['b','ind1','ind2','ind3'],['c',12,0,24],['d',0,0,0],['e',3,5,100]]
print(a)
b,c = a[:2],a[2:]
sorted(c,key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)
d = b+c
print(d)
```

But in this case it fails to sort and seems to return the original list. 
How do I address this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use itemgetter

```
 >>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L=[[0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't'], [9, 4, 'afsd']]
>>> sorted(L, key=itemgetter(2))
[[9, 4, 'afsd'], [0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't']]
```

It is also possible to use a lambda function here.

```
a.sort(key= lambda x: x[3])
```

But the lambda function is slower in this simple case